# menu not work after upgrade from 4.6 to 4.7.1 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, themes, megamenu

my right menu after upgrade from 4.6 to 4.7.1 in wp not work and not drop down.
my theme is HIMARKET...
how can solve this problem?

but in source view I can see categories but in front the mega menu not work !
Link : http://upskaraj.com/shop/